# handling for references affected by adding elements to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, reference, compiler-warnings, stdvector

As pointed out in [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588074/5132456), all pointers to a vector's elements may become invalid after new elements have been added to that vector, due to reallocation of the underlying contiguous buffer.

Is there a safe way to handle this issue at compile-time?

Are there best-practices to deal with or to avoid a situation, where references may become invalid after altering the data-structure?

Comment: in c# I will get an exception when I add elements while a iterator is active. Can I recreated this behavior in c++?

Comment: Can I tell the compiler to throw an error whenever I store a reference to a element in a vector? If so I might work around the issue by always getting the element by its index.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there best-practices to deal with or to avoid a situation, where references may become invalid after altering the data-structure?

- preallocate enough space for vector in advance
- keep index of object in array instead of reference/pointer to object itself
- use different container, for example `std::list`

which way will work for you the best way depends on your situation

Answer (score -1):

A pointer or reference to the std::vector itself won't change. What could change is the address of a specific element inside the std::vector due to reallocation policy which is implementation dependent.

Preallocating enough space is a risk because you shouldn't relay on a particular implementation policy.

Storing the address of an element in a std::vector is a bad idea and can be easily avoided because std::vector [] operator is very fast so store the index instead the address of the element. This the right way.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I think it's safe to assume that's what the OP meant, it just was worded poorly.